# Иконки рядом со списком

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер. С ЦСС знаком поверхностно, поэтому прошу помощи в некоем вопросе.

[image: снимок]

Как безболезненно сделать иконку справа от текста?

Comment: объявления показываются списком (li) float: left и float: right никакого эффекта не дают

Comment: возможно, вся новость и выводится элементов списка, но даже не вооружённым взглядом видно, что внутри этого элемента есть своя разметка - заголовок (или ссылка - не совсем понятно), текстовая часть, а в первой новости ещё и картинка. эту картинку можно ещё задать фоном для данного блока и разместить её в правом нижнем углу без повторения (но для этого нужна уверенность, что текст не "залезёт" на неё, т.е. будет достаточно короток)

Comment: ставил у картинки align="right" и подтягивал ее на 36 пкс вверх. текст налезал. на фон можно, но да, я забыл оговорить что картинку предполагается сделать кликабельной

Answer (score 0, accepted):

задать для иконки свойсто `float:left`  - [почиайте об этом здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/float)

но вообще иконка у Вас слева текстом обтекается....

попробуйте сделать `<a href="#"><span>Любой_текст</span></a>`. далее фоном для ссылки делаем эту картинку, а текст "задвигаем" text-indent на большое количество пикселей, например, влево....(например, на -1000px). текста будет не видно, ибо он сдвинется влево на -1000px, но будет доступен для синтезора речи, а картинка будет кликабельна.....